# Display height property continuously

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to display the height of a borderpane. I added this listener:

```
mainPane.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneHeight, Number newSceneHeight) {
                System.out.println("Height: " + newSceneHeight);
            }
        });
```

I would like to print the size continuously but unfortunately I get the size only once when I resize the stage.

Comment: You probably need to track the mouse manually...

Comment: What is the point of printing the size continuously if the size hasn't changed?

Comment: You could start a new Thread or schedule a repeating TimerTask and query the heightProperty from that task. But do not forget that FX is a single-threaded toolkit, so you would need to wrap the calls to the heightProperty by Platform.runLater.